# MATLAB: bounding the parameter values in nonlinear modelfitting and AICc scores

Tags: matlab, least-squares, nonlinear-functions, non-linear-regression

I am trying to fit a number of nonlinear models to a dataset, and I need to bound the model parameter values to all be positive.

I tried lsqcurvefit function and it works. However, I also need AICc scores for model comparison (as, apparently, adjusted R-squared scores are just no good.) It seems that lsqcurvefit doesn't compute such scores (?).

So I tried fitnlm which returns AICc. However, this time, I can't bound the parameter values (and as a result, I got some non-sensible negative parameter values).

Does anyone knows any MATLAB functions that simultaneously allow users to compute AICc scores and bound the parameter values at the same time? Alternative solutions, such as how to compute AICc from lsqcurvefit outputs, will also be very much appreciated.